Is there a command that can make blocks, for example, dirt, cracked mossy & stone bricks into slabs?
Me and some friends made a server for java 1.21 and my house's basement roof ended up having emerald blocks as the roof, I was wondering if there was any chance there could be a way to make slabs out of blocks that don't originally have slab variants with commands or command blocks.
This might just be a really stupid question, but I do just want to confirm it because I haven't found anybody talk about it with 100% certainty.

I doubt you are able to do this in-game (but am not familiar enough with the game to be certain), but here, for example, is a tutorial on how to make them outside the game.

If you are building this in Creative Mode, you could summon a block display that has the appearance of a slab.
To summon the block display:
/summon block_display (Position) {transformation:{left_rotation:[0f,0f,0f,1f],right_rotation:[0f,0f,0f,1f],translation:[0f,0f,0f],scale:[1f,0.5f,1f]},block_state:{Name:"(The block you wanted)"}}
If you want the block display to have a collision hitbox, place a slab inside the block display.
The slab may look like the squashed version of the block you want, but I think it's the only way to make a custom slab.
